# Swapping mutex locks

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I'm having trouble with properly "swapping" locks. Consider this situation:

```
bool HidDevice::wait(const std::function<bool(const Info&)>& predicate)
{
    /* A method scoped lock. */
    std::unique_lock waitLock(this->waitMutex, std::defer_lock);

    /* A scoped, general access, lock. */
    {
        std::lock_guard lock(this->mutex);

        bool exitEarly = false;

        /* do some checks... */

        if (exitEarly)
            return false;

        /* Only one thread at a time can execute this method, however
        other threads can execute other methods or abort this one. Thus,
        general access mutex "this->mutex" should be unlocked (to allow threads
        to call other methods) while at the same time, "this->waitMutex" should
        be locked to prevent multiple executions of code below. */

        waitLock.lock(); // How do I release "this->mutex" here?
    }

    /* do some stuff... */

    /* The main problem is with this event based OS function. It can 
    only be called once with the data I provide, therefore I need to 
    have a 2 locks - one blocks multiple method calls (the usual stuff) 
    and "waitLock" makes sure that only one instance of "osBlockingFunction" 
    is ruinning at the time. Since this is a thread blocking function,
    "this->mutex" must be unlocked at this point. */

    bool result = osBlockingFunction(...);

    /* In methods, such as "close", "this->waitMutex" and others are then used 
    to make sure that thread blocking methods have returned and I can safely
    modify related data. */

    /* do some more stuff... */

    return result;
}
```

How could I solve this "swapping" problem without overly complicating code? I could unlock `this->mutex` before locking another, however I'm afraid that in that nanosecond, a race condition might occur.

**Edit:**

Imagine that 3 threads are calling `wait` method. The first one will lock `this->mutex`, then `this->waitMutex` and then will unlock `this->mutex`. The second one will lock `this->mutex` and will have to wait for `this->waitMutex` to be available. It will not unlock `this->mutex`. The third one will get stuck on locking `this->mutex`.

I would like to get the last 2 threads to wait for `this->waitMutex` to be available.

**Edit 2:**

Expanded example with `osBlockingFunction`.

Comment: Does the logic require that the thread acquiring `waitLock` not loose `mutex` prior to acquiring `waitLock`?  E.g. it depends on the state executed under `mutex` to be unchanged once `waitLock` is held?

Comment: It smells like that the design/implementation should be a bit different with std::condition_variable on the HidDevice::wait() and only one mutex. And as you write "other threads can execute other methods or abort this one" will call .notify_one() to "abort" this wait. The wait unlocks the mutex atomically and on notify locks it atomically.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Yes.

Comment: @AmitG. I'm afraid you're right, I'll have to work with `std::condition_variable`s.

Comment: This is not a code problem.  It is a design problem.

Comment: The mutex that you're waiting on has to protect the shared state you're waiting for.

Comment: @AmitG. I tried implementing `std::condition_variable`, however I've had to go back to my multiple mutexes "solution" (after some compromises). The problem is that `/* do some stuff... */` has thread blocking OS function, which can be aborted via other OS function. However, I can't call that other function, because the mutex is locked after `this->cv.wait(...)`.

Comment: If one or more of your threads are on a blocking OS call without timeout than it is a problem: It may blocks endlessly & it's problematic to terminate a thread. When I had a similar situation, I externalized the blocking operation to a tiny-executable, and execute it asynchronous from the worker thread and wait for its done. It is possible to the executor to terminate/restart that process when necessary. But my case is not yours, so maybe it can't work for you.

Answer (score 3):

It smells like that the design/implementation should be a bit different with `std::condition_variable cv` on the `HidDevice::wait` and only one mutex. And as you write "other threads can execute other methods or abort this one" will call `cv.notify_one` to "abort" this wait. The `cv.wait` {enter wait & unlocks the mutex} atomically and on `cv.notify` {exits wait and locks the mutex} atomically. Like that `HidDevice::wait` is more simple:

```
bool HidDevice::wait(const std::function<bool(const Info&)>& predicate)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->m_Mutex); // Only one mutex.

    m_bEarlyExit = false;

    this->cv.wait(lock,  spurious wake-up check);

    if (m_bEarlyExit) // A bool data-member for abort. 
        return;

    /* do some stuff... */
}
```

- My assumption is (according to the name of the function) that on `/* do some checks... */` the thread waits until some logic comes true.

"Abort" the wait, will be in the responsibility of other `HidDevice` function, called by the other thread:

```
void HidDevice::do_some_checks() /* do some checks... */
{
    if ( some checks )
    {
        if ( other checks )
            m_bEarlyExit = true;

        this->cv.notify_one();
    }
}
```

Something similar to that.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a little "unlocker" facility.  This is a mutex wrapper with inverted semantics.  On `lock` it `unlocks` and vice-versa:

```
template <class Lock>
class unlocker
{
    Lock& locked_;

public:
    unlocker(Lock& lk) : locked_{lk} {}

    void lock() {locked_.unlock();}
    bool try_lock() {locked_.unlock(); return true;}
    void unlock() {locked_.lock();}
};
```

Now in place of:

```
waitLock.lock(); // How do I release "this->mutex" here?
```

You can instead say:

```
unlocker temp{lock};
std::lock(waitLock, temp);
```

where `lock` is a `unique_lock` instead of a `lock_guard` holding `mutex`.

This will lock `waitLock` and unlock `mutex` as if by one uninterruptible instruction.

---

And now, after coding all of that, I can reason that it can be transformed into:

```
waitLock.lock();
lock.unlock();  // lock must be a unique_lock to do this
```

Whether the first version is more or less readable is a matter of opinion.  The first version is easier to reason about (once one knows what `std::lock` does).  But the second one is simpler.  But with the second, the reader has to think more carefully about the correctness.

---

**Update**

Just read the edit in the question.  This solution does not fix the problem in the edit:  The second thread will block the third (and following threads) from making progress in any code that requires `mutex` but not `waitMutex`, until the first thread releases `waitMutex`.

So in this sense, my answer is technically correct, but does not satisfy the desired performance characteristics.  I'll leave it up for informational purposes.

Comment: So I read this answer and thought "that's rubbish".  Then I saw the author and decided it is *much* more likely I have misunderstood something!  So the first thing I had missed is that `std::lock` will call `.lock` on both `waitlock` and `temp` (and of course, calling `lock` on `temp` will actually *unlock* `lock`). I see the specification promises "no deadlocks", but I don't see anything that promises "no race conditions". (I'm reading [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock) rather than the standard.

Comment: I'm not above accidentally posting rubbish.  Wouldn't be the first time...  But so far I don't see a mistake in my logic, unless I've misunderstood something about the question.

Comment: @HowardHinnant I tried to clarify the problem I'm dreading about in the edit.

Comment: @FrogTheFrog:  Thanks for the clarification in your question.  You are correct that my answer does not address your concern.

Comment: I still see two problems with the "unlocker" approach.  Firstly, std::lock is guaranteed not to cause deadlock - but I bet the implementation assumes that it is `lock` that can hang (and that if it is going to do so, `try_lock` will fail).  However with "unlocker", it is the call to *unlock* that can hang (and there is no way to test if it is going to do so).

Comment: Secondly, I don't see anything in the specification of `std::lock` that says it will lock the mutexes in order.  Thus it can call `temp.lock()` first (and hence unlock `lock`), and `waitlock.lock` *second* - which leads to a race condition.

Comment: @MartinBonner:  I don't see a problem with `unlock()` hanging because it should never get called (but theoretically could because of the second problem).  The second problem is indeed a concern.  As far as I know, all implementations try the first lock first.  But you are correct that this is unspecified.  This makes the "transformation" the preferred approach.